# Setup kubectl context for remote cluster access

Tags: kubernetes, remote-access, kubectl

I have installed k8s on a bare metal cluster using `kubeadm init`.

Next I need to setup remote access for `kubectl`.  i.e. using `kubectl` from your laptop to access the remote cluster.

How do I setup the cluster, context, and credentials?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands to set the cluster, context, and credentials individually:

```
kubectl config set-cluster
kubectl config set-context
kubectl config set-credentials
```

If your not certain about the parameters to use for the credentials, i.e. client key/certs, its easier to copy the same exact credentials over to your cluster:

```
scp <username>@<master-node-ip>:/home/<username>/.kube/config ~/.kube/config
```

**Warning**: above command will overwrite any existing kube config file.  If so, its best to copy/paste over only the clusters, contexts, and credentials that you need to your local kube config file.

I found the kube config on the cluster already has the right keys and certificates.

Comment: I felt compelled to write up this question/answer.  It took me a while to figure this out, and I couldn't find anything describing this very simple approach.

Comment: credit: https://medium.com/@raj10x/configure-local-kubectl-to-access-remote-kubernetes-cluster-ee78feff2d6d